# Context menu on click of image

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one image view and want context menu should be opened when i clicked on the image , is any one know the logic behind that , please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Greendroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid), specifically QuickActions.